# Filling null values in dataset

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Iam getting this error when Iam filling null values with mean with pandas.

```
def random_values_fill(feature):
    random_values = data[feature].dropna().sample(data[feature].isnull().sum())
    random_values.index = data[data[feature].isnull()].index
    data.loc[data[feature].isnull(),feature] = random_values
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\PycharmProjects\machine_learning\powerco-cuschurn.py", line 27, in <module>
    random_values_fill(col)
  File "C:\Users\PycharmProjects\machine_learning\powerco-cuschurn.py", line 22, in random_values_fill
    random_values = data[feature].dropna().sample(data[feature].isnull().sum())
  File "C:\Users\PycharmProjects\machine_learning\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 5343, in sample
    elif frac is None and n % 1 != 0:
  File "C:\Users\PycharmProjects\machine_learning\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 1534, in __nonzero__
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

What is the mistake here?

Comment: PLease show a subset of the dataframe - we have no idea what the error could be when we don't know what the data looks like

Comment: It seems like you are dropping all Nan values with your dropna() and then taking a sample and then looking for Nan with isnull(). But since you have already dropped them they shouldn't be present.

Comment: finally I cleared it